# Easy way to plot potential energy curves?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, chemistry

I need to plot the potential energy curves, i.e. to do something similar to this:

[image]

I know, that I could use `pgfplots` to get the curves, but what I'm troubled about are the labels - I'd like to do both the curves' labels and the dissociation limits' labels (in the red rectangle) in a very same manner as here and I don't know, if it's possible easily in `pgfplots`.

Also, I was trying to find some package already offering this functionality, but I've found only [endiagram](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/endiagram/endiagram_en.pdf) which, while looking good, is meant more for teaching purposes, than for data-plotting.

So, would you, please, recommend me some easy way to do this, if possible?

Comment: It certainly is possible to reproduce the graph. I would suggest that you provide us with everything except the labels and legend and we will do the rest. Up to now it is a "just do the the graphics" question which usually gets closed as "off-topic" when not someone with much time does everything for you.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Ok, I'll supplement the plot asap.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do that, by using the `\node` function of pgfplots, you can add a position where you want to have each of the labels.

I personally would use a legend that is outside the diagram for labeling the individual curves. But there are a dozend ways to do the legends, these can be found in chapter 4.9 of the `pgfplots` documentation.